# AWS DMS - How can we get the source column names when using target endpoint as S3 and .CSV file ? Is it possible?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, cdc, aws-dms

AWS DMS - How can we get the source column names when using target endpoint as S3 and .CSV file ? Is it possible? I get the column names when using .parquet but not .CSV

Also I do not get the OP column when using the CDC option. As mentioned in AWS forum, it does not give me the an additional col which can have I, U or D values based on insert , update and delete from source.

Note: My source is on-prem Oracle and the logging is enabled at source level for all cols on the table

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an extra connection attribute when creating the S3 target endpoint.  The attribute and value to set are `addColumnName=true;`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html#CHAP_Target.S3.Configuring

The OP column only appears in CDC files, they will be named something that looks like `20141029-1134010000.csv.`.  The full load files, named something like `LOAD00000001.csv` will by default not contain an OP column.  If you want to change that behavior you can set this extra attribute when creating the target endpoint:  `includeOpForFullLoad=true;`